# Difference between having @staticmethod and not having it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

In Python 3.x what can I do with `bar()` that I cannot do with `foo()`?

```
class A:
    def foo():
        print("some code")

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print("some code")
```

*Note: I initially forgot to specify `self` as an argument to `foo()`, but I'm leaving the mistake there, since the answers andress that.*

Comment: The definition of `foo` should be `def foo(self):`  if you are planning to call it :)

Comment: this is not valid. foo will fail, since it requires a reference to self `foo(self)`

Comment: Please do not change the question, I have already addressed your initial version - and it is worth leaving in the answer..

Comment: The difference is readily apparent once `self` is added as an argument. The function would never run without `self` anyways

Comment: So should I revert it to its original form with the error and leave an edit note, so some other learner can pick up on it?

Comment: probably revert it and paste under it the correct way. also, it'd be helpful accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `staticmethod` is a method that does not require an object as its first parameter. This means it is a method useful to the class itself and all instantiations of it, rather than just instances of it (object initialized as `A()`.

What this means in practical terms, is that Python does not implicitly send the object itself as a parameter. Your first method will break once you call it:

```
>>> a.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

This is because Python supplies object methods with the object itself as a first parameter. Hence the ubiquitous self argument:

```
def foo(self): #Proper signature
```

On the other hand,

```
A.bar()
```

will work just fine, and so will

```
a.bar()
```

The object is not supplied as a first argument. Use `staticmethod`s for methods that are supposed to be helpful to the class and its instances, but do not require knowledge of either. Usually I use these as utility functions.

**Note there is a third version**, a `classmethod`, which is similar to a regular method in that it accepts a first parameter by default - the class of the caller. In this case the minimal signature is

```
@classmethod
def operateOnClass(cls):
```

Use this to make changes that affect all instances, such as changing class variables.

Comment: Maybe it's important to mention that python has three types of methods: instance methods, class methods and static methods.

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on that so I can get a fuller picture

Comment: @Will Done. Each is useful for something a bit different.

Answer (score 3):

`bar()` can be called from an uninstantiated class object. `foo()` needs to be fed `self` as an argument, and as such can only be called from an object already declared as an instance of `class A`